# Equivalence of weak induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction, first-order-logic, logic-translation

Let $P(n)$ be an open statement about $n\in \mathbb{N}$. In the weak induction, beside the base case, it is stated:

> $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}(P(k)\implies P(k+1))$$\qquad (i)$

But, in this [page](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MATH_220_Discrete_Math/3%3A_Proof_Techniques/3.6%3A_Mathematical_Induction_-_An_Introduction) right in the beginning, it states differently, according to my understanding (with $a=1$)

> $((\exists k\in \mathbb{N}) P(k))\implies P(k+1)$$\qquad (ii)$

Are the statements  (i) and (ii) equivalent? If yes, why?

Comment: The statement in the link is "If $P(k)$ is true for some $k$ then it is true for $k+1$ ". Since you have a base case, it is true for $k=2$, and since it is true for $k=2$ it is true for $k=$, etc... So yes, it's the same

Comment: Are you sure it's $\exists k\in P(k)$ and not $\exists k \in\mathbb{N}(P(k))$ ?

Comment: @Moosh It was a typo. I fixed it

Comment: The quantifier on variable $k$ is out of scope in the consequent of the second implication. Is it intended that these are the same $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following sentence: "If something is a cube, then it is large"

At first sight, you might be inclined to translate this to:

$\exists x \ Cube(x) \to Large(x)$

but this has a problem: the $x$ in $Large(x)$ is a free variable, and as such it has lost its connection to the $x$ in $(Cube(x)$

Adding it to the scope of the existential quantifier:

$\exists x \ (Cube(x) \to Large(x))$

doesn't help, because *that* sentence would be vacuously true as soon as there is something that is not a cube ... which is clearly not what we want either.

Instead, you should realize that by 'some', we really just mean 'any one', i.e. you need to use a universal. That is, what the sentence means is: "Anything that is a cube is large" ... and now you see that the correct formalization is:

$\forall x \ (Cube(x) \to Large(x))$

The same is going on in your case.

On the linked page, it states:

> if P(k) is true for some integer k≥a, then P(k+1) is also true.

Ignoring the $a$, it looks as if this translates to (as you suggest):

> $((\exists k\in \mathbb{N}) P(k))\implies P(k+1)$$\qquad (ii)$

but as with the earlier example, the problem is that in this formula, the $k$ in $P(k+1)$ ends up being free, whereas it should clearly refer to the very same $k$ used in $P(k)$.

What the authors try to say is that "if some number $k$ has property $P$, then its successor (i.e. $k+1$) has property $P$ as well", and as with the earlier example, we now realize that this translates to your i):

> $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}(P(k)\implies P(k+1))$$\qquad (i)$

So no, your given statements i) and ii) are not equivalent, but the authors didn't mean to express ii) in the first place: what they say also translates to i)

Comment: Wow, thanks for a detailed answer. Why would anyone express like this way, "Assume $P(k)$ is true for some $k\geq 0$, and use this to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true", when it could easily be misunderstood about the quantifier? Is this how the everyday-language is translated into? Would it not have been better to say: "Given an arbitrary $k\geq 0$, assume that $P(k)$ is true. Use this to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true"?

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor Well, natural language is notoriously ambiguous, but that’s the price you pay for efficiency. So this is one important reason for our mathematical languages like logic: they serve to disambiguate